# Ember many to many relationship - add a new object if one does not already exist

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I have two models with a many to many relationship to each other - the first is 'recipe', the second is 'tag':

```
App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.FixtureAdapter.extend({});

App.Recipe = DS.Model.extend({
    title: attr('string'),
    source: attr('string'),
    notes: attr('string'),
    isFavourite: attr('boolean', {defaultValue: false}),
    tags: hasMany('tag', { async: true })
});

App.Tag = DS.Model.extend({
    name: attr('string'),
    recipes: hasMany('recipe', { async: true })
});
```

In my template, I have an input for adding a tag to a recipe.
User can add either one tag, or multiple by separating each tag with a comma.

```
{{input type="text" enter="AddTags" placeholder="add a tag (or two!)"}}
```

This calls 'AddTags' within my RecipeController:

```
App.RecipeController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    actions: {
        AddTags: function(tags){
            var store = this.store;
            var thisRecipe = this.get('model');
            var thisRecipeTags = thisRecipe.get('tags');
            var addedTags = tags.split(',');

            for (i = 0; i < addedTags.length; i++) {
                tag = store.createRecord('tag', {
                    name: addedTags[i]
                });

                thisRecipeTags.addObject(tag);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

This works wonderfully - **however** - I would like to refactor the function so that a new tag is only created *if* one with the same name doesn't already exist:

```
AddTags: function(tags){
    var store = this.store;
    var thisRecipe = this.get('model');
    var thisRecipeTags = thisRecipe.get('tags');
    var addedTags = tags.split(',');
    for (i = 0; i < addedTags.length; i++) {
        // If exisiting tag where name == addedTags[i]
            tag = existing tag object here
        // Else create a new tag
            tag = store.createRecord('tag', {
                name: addedTags[i]
            });

        thisRecipeTags.addObject(tag);
    }
}
```

How can I do this?

Update: I have set up a JS bin with the relevant code here: http://jsbin.com/kixexe/1/edit?js,output

Answer (score 2):

Working demo [here](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/lurome/3/edit?html,js,console,output)

Now for some explanation...

You are using `DS.FixtureAdapter` in your jsbin, which requires you to implement a `queryFixtures` method if you are going to query fixtures (see [here](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/1.0.0-beta.15/packages/ember-data/lib/adapters/fixture_adapter.js#L88)) like you are doing when querying by name. A quick implementation of this could be as follows:

```
MyApp.TagAdapter = DS.FixtureAdapter.extend({
    queryFixtures: function(fixtures, query){
      var result = [];
      var tag = fixtures.findBy('name', query.name);
      if(tag){
        result.push(tag);
      }

    return result;
  }
});
```

When you query the store, you get back a promise which you can go into by using `then()`

If you didn't find anything - you can just move on with what you had before...

If you **did** find an existing tag - you can add it to other tags and then save the tags and the recipe records, since this is a many-to-many relationship.

**UPDATE**

Updated solution [here](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/lurome/7/edit?html,js,output)

The `for` loop you had was getting confused especially when using promises, this is usually NOT what you want. Instead, Ember has a more typical/functional approach of `forEach()` I also trimmed the whitespace on the ends of the tags, since this is probably what you want using `map()`. See [here](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Enumerable.html) to learn more about `map()` and `forEach()`

```
// trim whitespace
var addedTags = tags.split(',').map(function(str){ 
   return  str.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/gm,'');
});

// loop through tags
addedTags.forEach(function(tagName){
  store.find('tag', { name: tagName }).then(function(results){
    if(results.content.length){
      thisRecipeTags.addObject(results.content[0]);  
      thisRecipeTags.save();
      thisRecipe.save();
    } 
    else {
      var tag = store.createRecord('tag', {
        name: tagName
      });
      thisRecipeTags.addObject(tag);
      thisRecipeTags.save();
      thisRecipe.save();                    
    }
  });
});
```

**UPDATE #2**

The tag was not being properly removed. Because this is a 2-way mapping, apparently you need to remove tag from the recipe (which you were doing) and ALSO recipe from the tag, which you were NOT doing. The updated code looks as follows:

```
removeTag: function(tag) {
  var recipe = this.get('model');
  recipe.get('tags').removeObject(tag);
  tag.get('recipes').removeObject(recipe.get('id'));
  tag.save();
  recipe.save();
},
```

Working (hopefully for real this time ;) solution [here](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/lurome/11/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: Thanks for your reply and the demo.  There are still a couple of problems.  1.  If you enter "yummy" into the first recipe, it works fine.  But if you then try to add "yummy" to the second, a new tag is created (instead of applying the first tag).  2. There seems to be a lot of problems when adding (and then removing) multiple tags separated by commas.

Comment: Fixed #1 http://emberjs.jsbin.com/lurome/4/edit?html,js,console,output I was not saving recipe and tags and apparently needed to since it is a many-to-many. Can you give me a specific scenario for #2?

Comment: In the first input box - add "one, two" - you will get two tags, both named "two".

Comment: Thanks again for your answer, particularly for supplying links.  I'm still not sure that this is working properly.  Try this: add "one, two" to the first recipe, then "one, two" to the second.  So far so good.  Now remove these from both recipes (but not delete altogether).  Now add "one, two" to the first recipe.  It attaches them to both!  I'm not sure if this is because of the add or remove function and may be out of the scope of this question.

Comment: I am able to duplicate it (and now I got 6 days to fix it :))

Answer (score 1):

You can search for an existing tag as follows:

```
var existing = store.find('tag', { name: addedTags[i] });
```

So, you can have logic along the lines of:

```
AddTags: function(tags){
    var store = this.store;
    var thisRecipe = this.get('model');
    var thisRecipeTags = thisRecipe.get('tags');
    var addedTags = tags.split(',');
    for (i = 0; i < addedTags.length; i++) {
        var existing = store.find('tag', { name: addedTags[i] });
        if(existing){
            tag = existing        
        } else {
            tag = store.createRecord('tag', {
                name: addedTags[i]
            });        
        }

        thisRecipeTags.addObject(tag);
    }
}
```

I can't test this at the moment so it might need some changes to account for promises, etc -- but that should get you more or less what you need.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I am getting a "TypeError: e._relationships is undefined" error locally.  I have setup a JS bin here: http://jsbin.com/kixexe/1/edit?js,output for testing.